# Encode non-ASCII characters to HTML using Javascript/Windows batch file hybrid

Tags: javascript, html, windows, batch-file, html-entities

I need to replicate the exact function this website http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php does in a hybrid Javascript/Windows batch script. I have zero knowledge about Javascript but it seems it is the easiest (for those knowledgeable) possible way to replace special non-ASCII characters with their HTML entity equivalents within text files: "**têxt**" to "**t&#234;xt**", for example, but using input and output text files instead of web forms. I've seen the wonders JREPL.bat (a regex/find and replace tool) does so I thought this could be achieved.

Pardon me for asking this question but this is part of a problem I could not wrap my head around for days. It is in regard to this unanswered question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121949/curl-data-urlencode-posts-broken-non-english-characters. I figured out that the Japanese and other UTF-8 characters in the text file can be passed through CURL post request without being garbled by first encoding them to HTML code before the --data-urlencode part.

That said, I am kindly asking if someone would be so kind as to create a simple JScript/Windows batch script hybrid incorporating the Javascript code the above-mentioned website uses to encode *only* non-ASCII characters to HTML entities within a text file which I can call from another batch file using a line of code like this:

```
CALL EncodetoHTML.bat -i "input.txt" -o "output.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own script. It took me a whole day basically scouring the Internet for useful pieces of code I could find and combining them to achieve the effect I wanted.

Save the code below to tohtmlent.bat. Use it from CMD like `tohtmlent.bat filename.txt` or call it from another batch file like `call tohtmlent.bat filename.txt` where "filename.txt" is the input file. Output will be displayed in the console so use `>` if you would like to pipe the output to a file. The input file should strictly be encoded in UTF-8. Output is ANSI. What the script does is it converts all Unicode characters with decimal range 128 and higher to their numeric HTML entity equivalents.

The code is nowhere near elegant considering I am not a programmer and it still has a lot more room for improvement. But hey, it does its job!

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /*
@echo off
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0
*/

if (WScript.Arguments.Length < 1 ) {
    WScript.Echo("No file specified.");
    WScript.Quit(0)
}

var inputFile = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var fso= new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var inputFile=WScript.Arguments.Item(0);

if (!fso.FileExists(inputFile)){
    WScript.Echo(inputFile + " does not exist.");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

var objAdoS = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
objAdoS.Type = 2;
objAdoS.CharSet = "utf-8";
objAdoS.Open();
objAdoS.LoadFromFile(inputFile);
var strInput = objAdoS.ReadText();
objAdoS.Close();
var strOutput = '';
for(i=0; i<strInput.length; i++){
    if(strInput.charCodeAt(i)>127){ strOutput += '&#' + strInput.charCodeAt(i) + ';'; }else{ strOutput += strInput.charAt(i); }
}
WScript.Echo(strOutput);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here it is](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/toHtmlEnt.bat) . Brand new and fresh.

You can pass only the file you want to encode (the result will be printed to the console) or pass input and output file.Examples:

```
call toHtmlEnt.bat input.txt output.txt
call toHtmlEnt.bat input.txt
```

Comment: I am yest to test this, You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Hello. I already tested your script. `call toHtmlEnt.bat input.txt output.txt` outputted weird characters when I tried Japanese characters in the input text file. `call toHtmlEnt.bat input.txt > output.txt` works fine though. BUT! It still converted some ASCII characters to HTML code specifically characters **&**, **i**, **<**, **>**, and **I**. Could you revise your script allowing ALL 0-127 ASCII characters? Please refer here for the list of ASCII characters: http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html

Comment: @zcalebz - hmm.. I'm reading the file as plain ASCII text.Rather I need to add UTF-8 support and I'll need to think a little bit.

Comment: Oh no! I thought it worked correctly, but actually not! **大日本帝國** was encoded to **&#229;&#164;&#167;&#230;&#8212;&#165;&#230;&#339;&#172;&#229;&#184;?&#229;&#339;&#8249;** which if you decode is the gibberish **å¤§æ—¥æœ¬å¸?åœ‹**. Please fix it!

Edit: Can't you do it using just the `function a(b)` and `function sampleText()` js code from the page source of http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php?

Comment: @zcalebz - writing a version with a custom encoding support.Have a little patience :-).

Comment: I am patient. I was just a bit too excited. Thanks!